# Streaming of response using Langchain is Typescript

Tags: typescript, openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to write a code which finds the topK matching vectors from Pinecone and return a summary of the asked question based on the topK results.

For this I'm using LangChain with OpenAI ( to create embeddings ) in typescript.

This is the code :

```
import { PineconeClient } from "@pinecone-database/pinecone";
import { VectorDBQAChain } from "langchain/chains";
import { PineconeStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";



const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
    openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});


const pinecone = new PineconeClient();

const model = new OpenAI({
    openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});



async function main(namespaceID: string) {


    await pinecone.init({
        apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY,
        environment: "us-west4-gcp-free",
    });

    const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index("index-test");


    const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
        embeddings,
        { pineconeIndex }
    );

    vectorStore.namespace = namespaceID

    const chain = VectorDBQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStore, {
        k: 5,
        returnSourceDocuments: true,
        verbose: true,
    });
    const response = await chain.call({ query: "What is the status of Project X" });
    console.log(response);



}


main("TEST_NAMESPACE")
```

This code works fine. Now I want to be able to stream the response from chain.call() to my console.

Any solution or possibly a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a modified version of the last part of the code you provided which enables streaming the response:

```
let streamedResponse = "";
const streamingModel = new ChatOpenAI({
    streaming: true,
    callbacks: [{
        handleLLMNewToken(token) {
            streamedResponse += token;
        },
    }],
    openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});
const chain = VectorDBQAChain.fromLLM(streamingModel, vectorStore, {
    k: 5,
    returnSourceDocuments: true,
    verbose: true,
});
const response = await chain.call({
    query: "What is the status of Project X"
});
console.log({ streamedResponse });
```

You will need to add a new import:

```
import { ChatOpenAI } from 'langchain/chat_models/openai'
```

[LangChain documentation on Streaming](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/index_related_chains/conversational_retrieval#streaming)